# Orthogonal projection over a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

I tried to solve the orthogonal projection problem below:

**"Let's F = [(1,1,-1)], the orthogonal projection of (2,4,1) under the orthogonal subspace of F is:"**

The formula I used was:

=> Proj V under U = (V*U/U*U) * U

=> V*U = (2,4,1) * (1,1,-1) = 2*1+4*1+(1*-1) = 2+4-1 = 5

=> U*U = (1,1,-1) * (1,1,-1) = 1*1+1*1+(-1*-1) = 1+1+1 = 3

=> (5/3)*(1,1-1)

=> **(5/3, 5/3, -5/3)**

The possible answers are:

A) (1,2,3)

B) (1/3, 7/3, 8/3)

C) (1/3, 2/3, 8/3)

D) (0, 0, 0)

E) (1, 1, 1)

Could someone spot the error and give a step by step solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you tried to compute the orthogonal projection of $(2,4,1)$ on $\bigl\langle(1,1,-1)\bigr\rangle$, whereas you should orthogonal projection on $\bigl\langle(1,1,-1)\bigr\rangle^\perp$.

By the way, the correct answer is B). You can do it as follows:

1. First, take a basis of $\bigl\langle(1,1,-1)\bigr\rangle$. I took $(1,0,1)$ and $(0,1,1)$.
2. Apply Gram-Schmidt to this basis in order to get an orthonormal basis. I got the basis $e_1=\frac1{\sqrt2}(1,0,1)$ and $e_2=\frac1{\sqrt6}(-1,2,1)$.
3. Finally, compute $\bigl((2,4,1).e_1\bigr)e_1+\bigl((2,4,1).e_2\bigr)e_2$.

Note that the final result will always be the same, no matter the choice of the basis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you point me a step by step method to get the answer B.?

Comment: @marcoshass Done. I hope that all is clear now.

Comment: I'm studying this topic of orthogonal projection without a professor and some parts are still not clear to me such as "1. First, take a basis of ⟨(1,1,−1)⟩" ... Do you have a reference for a book/website from where I could learn how to develop this exercise? I "think" this question relates to "Analytical Geometry" am I right?
Thanks again!
Marcos

Comment: @marcoshass No. This is about Linear Algebra.

Comment: @marcoshass An even simpler way to get the correct answer is to subtract the vector you computed—the projection onto $F$—from the original vector, leaving its orthogonal *rejection* from $F$, which is the same as its orthogonal projection onto $F^\perp$.

Comment: @amd Nice technique ;-) "An even simpler way to get the correct answer is to subtract the vector you computed the projection onto F" 
5/3 - 2 = -1/3; 5/3 - 4 = -7/3; -5/3-1 = -8/3. I 'believe' I have to put a modulus operator around the results |-1/3|, |-7/3|, |-5/3| will result in the answer B.

Comment: @marcoshass No, but you do need to get the subtrahends in the correct order in the first place.